# Issues for decreasing coverage in SonarQube

Tags: continuous-integration, sonarqube, code-coverage

We would like to have SonarQube create issues for falling coverage on a pull request.

I know there are existing rules for comparing the coverage to a fixed, configurable threshold and there is a quality gate for falling coverage.

We want to show our developers hints the locations (files) where the coverage decreases.

I looked at the different plugin extension points but there seems to be no way to access raw metrics from extension rules, only the builtin rules are allowed to do so.

Comment: what is the version of SonarQube used?

Comment: At the moment its 5.6 LTS

Answer (score 0):

- use Quality Gates to enforce code coverage on new code delivered. Here's [an example](https://sonarqube.com/quality_gates/show/4). You can then explore files on new code with less coverage (project page > measures > coverage). That's what we rely on at SonarSource.
- activate the rules on [line](https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=common-java%3AInsufficientLineCoverage) or [branch](https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=common-java%3AInsufficientBranchCoverage) coverage

Comment: The idea is to have issues on the files for the programmers to have a concrete hint where the issue is.